# Rewrite url in yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

How can I rewrite urls in Yii2. I want to rewrite url

> /post/index?id=1

to

> /post/1-example

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following `rules` code for `urlManager` in `config/main.php`(if advance template) or `web.php`.

```
[
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                   'post/<id:\d+>-example' => 'post/index',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                   'post/<id:\d+>-<title:\w+>' => 'post/index',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code to your `backend/config/main.php` under components section:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',),
],
```

I'd posted just because ians should be generic for all entire project.