# How to hide id query in Yii2 Url

Tags: url, yii2, config, pretty-urls

I've this Url "**backend/codici/view?id=1**" and I want to hide the id, because I don't want to show it. It must be only "**backend/codici**". I try enabling Pretty Url but it doesn't work.
This my config/web.php file:

```
'urlManager' => [
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'rules' => [],
],
```

What I have to do to solve it? thank you very much!!!!

Comment: How else will you identify view that should be displayed - without ID parameter? Perhaps you mean that you want to mask it e.g. replace `id=123` with something like `id=XYZMASKEID` .. ?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012312/rewrite-url-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1

Is there just one record of type `codici`? If yes, replace the `CodiciController::actionIndex()` method in order to instead of listing all `codici` records, load the one (`Codici::findOne()`) and render `view` file instead of `index`. Basically copy paste the content of `actionView()` but instead of load model by id, load the existing one.

I'm assuming default code generated by Gii for a `codici` table in your database.

Scenario 2

If there is more than one record, then you have 2 options:

- to pass the ID via query string (default, like it is now)
- use a POST request instead of GET request, the ID will not be shown in the URL, but it requires some **magic** in the link. Also note that a regular view page should not be requested via POST, but via GET.